# How to forward client ip to App server via Haproxy TCP/IP loadbalancer?

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, tcpip

I have configured HAproxy for TCP/IP loadbalancing but in app server I am not getting IP address of source instead of that I'm getting haproxy IP address as client ip address.

I searched on google and I got so many article to setup proxy-forwarding in HTTP mode but i'm not getting any method to enable same in TCP/IP mode.
Please help me with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get the client IP address in TCP mode, since there is no mechanism to relay the original IP address to the application server.

Comment: is there any way to achieve this by using IPTables?

Comment: That might be possible, search for "iptables load balancer" and you will find articles about the subject.